# How can I query all post with currrent taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy, query, terms

I created the taxonomy 'machine types', and added several terms to it, like 'cranes' for example.

The url to that term now looks like this: domain.com/machine-types/cranes

How can I make this url query for only posts with the term cranes? And the same for all other terms, without creating a template for each term.

I think I must ask for the current term and store it in a value, and query for that, right? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `taxonomy.php` file and put your loop/query inside this file and as such anytime you are on a taxonomy page, no matter the term, be it cranes, bulldozers, etc the `taxonomy.php` will take over and handle the term in question (as shown in your URL).

Taken from the WordPress Codex, this is the template hierarchy - the order in which what files take precedence over another for taxonomy pages.

> ## **Custom Taxonomies display**
>
> - **taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{slug}.php** - If the taxonomy were sometax, and taxonomy's slug were someterm WordPress would look for taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php. In the case of Post Formats, the taxonomy is 'post_format' and the terms are 'post-format-{format}.
>     i.e. taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php
> - **taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php** - If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress would look for taxonomy-sometax.php
> - **taxonomy.php**
> - **archive.php**
> - **index.php**

So as you can see if you need to you can also customize the template file right up to the individual taxonomy term, or taxonomy (if you have more than one).

Comment: Thanks. I have several different taxonomies which I might want to display differently, so I ended up using taxonomy-mytaxonomy.php.